# Parallel processing Windows batch file

Tags: java, windows, parallel-processing, batch-processing

I have a pretty big number of files that need to be converted to a different format. The converting is done via a Java-JAR-File that gets takes the filename as a parameter. I now have a Windows batchfile that uses a for loop to loop through all the files (there is a file that contains a list of all files that need to be converted)

```
for /F %%i in (all_files.txt) do call java -cp %Classpath% de.xyz.Convert -xml %%i .\xml
```

Now the machine I want to do this on has eight cores. The number of files is about 360.000 and I would like it to take as little time as possible, so I'd like to use as many cores as possible. How would I go about using multiple cores as easy as possible? Is Windows going to be doing that on its own?

Comment: Surely allowing this to be managed by a single JVM would reduce overhead. Modify your jar to take an input directory and process all files from that directory into an output directory, then allow this to be multi-threaded. :) - I think your issue here is likely to be disk read speed.

Comment: I can't modify the jar file unfortunately, it's "proprietary". :/

Comment: Well maybe with a lot of reverse engineering I could, but I don't really have the time to do that.

Comment: Given that you are allowed to use the jar, I would consider creating a wrapper runnable for it, no need to modify the jar specifically, just use it as a library. I just don't like the idea of spawning 360,000 instances of the JVM, one at a time...

Comment: Do you have a quick example of how you'd be doing this in this exact case? Use the JAR file as a library in a separate Java application that then creates threads running the de.xyz.Convert programm?

Comment: I'm not well versed when it comes to thread programming in Java. Would I be creating 360000 threads at once and the JVM and the OS will handle their execution? Or do I need to be creating only as many threads, like 8, at a time and wait for one to finish before creating the next? :)

Comment: You could create a pool of threads, and a collection of runnable instances. This thread pool can be a specified size, or can adjust in accordance with requirement, but the JVM would then handle the execution of each runnable using each thread as it becomes available. So, you would create your thread pool, and then queue each of the 360,000 runnable instances, which until they actually run will only need to contain the filename that they will process.

Comment: You could consider using [start](http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm) - it runs the command in a new window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, because I hadn't actually done it before, I knocked this up. It's not great, and the lib I used was a jar I created to crash after 2 mins.. Hopefully you'll be able to reverse engineer this for your needs.

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        BlockingQueue<Runnable> runnableQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        ExecutorService executorServ = new ThreadPoolExecutor(8, 8, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, runnableQueue);
        runnableQueue.add(new RunCrash("Example")); // Add one for each file...
        executorServ.shutdown();
        while(!executorServ.isTerminated()) {
            // running
        }
    }
}

class RunCrash implements Runnable {

    private String fileName;
    RunCrash(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(fileName);
        try {
            crash.CrashMe.main(new String[]{fileName});
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Oh, you can let the main thread die before the others finish, I believe the JVM will keep the executor and associated queue. :)

Comment: Thanks. That's a great starting point. Letting the main thread die you mean I could remove the while loop?

Currently I'm struggling with the runnableQueue being full after adding just one thread. Guess I'll have to do some reading :)

Comment: yeah, you can remove the while loop. erm... try using a LinkedBlockingQueue instead of a SynchronousQueue... that should allow you to queue more than one Runnable at a time... (sorry I kinda rushed this and didn't check all of the api for relevance.)

Comment: No problem! I've found a different example where they are using ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);, which I am now using as well. I then executorService.execute(new Converter(fileName)) and that might be working. Unfortunately the JAR file now seems to be needing some apache classes which I guess I will have to add as external libraries on my own or something... I will report back when I got that working :)

Comment: Ok I got it to work. I compared the threaded programm with a simple for-loop with 40 files. The threaded program took 83 seconds to complete, the simple loop took 85 seconds. Not sure why there isn't more of a difference. Might have done something wrong, but maybe there just isn't much of a difference. I have just four cores in this machine, we'll see how it works on the 8 core machine. If I calculated correctly, 40 files at 85 seconds would mean more than 200 hours if converting... :/

Comment: Ran it again and now those 40 files are converted in 86 seconds with both methods. Guess there isn't much of a difference. Not sure why though. Maybe the "thread management" the JVM has to do takes just as much time as the multithreaded operation saves. Or maybe somehow that for loop calling the convertion method in the JAR lib somehow makes threads as well? Any ideas? Maybe over the course of 360k files there will be some saving.

Comment: It's more the memory consideration - 360k instances trying to share CPU loading files into memory will mean you'll likely end up running into hardfaults with memory, whereas this will allow a more consistent and hopefully lower memory usage. check the memory graphs for your 40file test - it should still be evident there. :)

Comment: Can't really see a difference so far. I think using it with the threads is probably better still. But I also don't think there are 360k instances at the same time when just starting the convert lib via a for loop, it seems like one convertion is finished before the next one starts. Or am I not understanding you correctly?

Comment: 360k instances would be created if you used the start instead of the call command.. which would kill the memory. The threaded java solution I expect would be your best performance overall and would be limited by disk read/write, or CPU based on the performance of the lib you are using and the hardware. I'm just concerned that 40 files taking 80+ seconds suggests it will take you 8+ days for all of your files...

Comment: Yea, that's what I came up with as well, it'll take about 8.5 days. And then I'll have to do some more stuff with the 360k XML files as well, but that'll go much quicker. Hopefully it won't crash half way through. :-D